# Can Users with bucket-writer access list bucket objects in GCS?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

If I have a bucket with `allUsers-WRITER` ACL. Can users list objects inside the bucket or just write/delete objects in the bucket?

Can they also ask to delete a directory or execute delete or write operations on a glob expression? Like: `gsutil rm gs://mybucket/**` Basically without providing the full path of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a note. GCS has two access methods: [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) and [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists). If an operation is permitted by either mechanism, then the operation is permitted.

That said, within the concept of ACLs, granting the permission WRITER to the group "allUsers" grants every user, including anonymous users, the power to list, create, overwrite, and delete any objects in a bucket. It is a superset of the bucket READER permission.

It does not, however, grant permission to read individual objects.

Comment: Thanks for the IAM pointer. This might allow more control over permissions. Will read some more about these.